# Success message appearing two times after submitting form

Tags: yii2

I am a beginner at yii2. I have tried to make a form in yii2, but it gives a success message two times. how do I fix it?

[image]

What is the issue in my code please check. Here is my code:

The model which I have created:

[image]

controller:

[image]

The view page:

[image]

Comment: If using yii2 basic template check `main.php` in views, alert widget is there, no need to add `hasFlash()` or anything every file.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `hasFlash` condition from views page, its already loaded in `main.php` as `<?= Alert::widget() ?>`